# FTP file upload

Tags: cron

What cron settings send local file (`/home/pi/file.txt`) upload via vsftpd (`ftp://server/file.txt`)?

I am using a Rapsberry Pi 3 with raspbian jessie, apache, mysql, php5, vsftpd.

Comment: What OS are you using? What ftp client do you have installed? What did you try so far?

Comment: Since this isn't specific to the RPi in anyway, your question is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably to make a script similar to

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp server << END
put /home/pi/file.txt
END
```

and save it, for the sake of the example, as `/home/pi/ftpscript`. Remember to make it executable.

Then

```
crontab -e
```

and add

```
0 2 * * * /home/pi/ftpscript
```

at the end. This will upload the file at 2 each morning.

Comment: Hi, cron call OK.       ftp -uUSER -pPASS SERVER - not uplod afile :-//

Comment: @user2851761 I'm sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: cron not problem backup mysql to dir /home/pi/backup

Comment: mysql backup not send my server www.domain.com in internet via FTP